# Where to catch exceptions from customized ModelBinder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

I have a customized ModelBinder which bind web from with a object using code like this"

```
    [ModelBinder(typeof(CustomizedModelBinder))]
    public class Widget{ ... }
```

This modelbinder may throw exceptions and where should I add code to catch those exceptions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From design perspective it is better for a model binder to add model errors instead of throwing exceptions:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Phone", "Phone number is invalid.");
```

This way, later in your action you could check if the model is valid:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I still would like to keep on view page which will be redirected after a exception is catched.

Comment: how to do it, not in controller? It is bad idea to has Model.IsValid in every controller in every command action.